# Right way to overload < operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class called user which has a lname field. Is this the right way to overload the "<" operator?

```
bool User::operator<(const User& other)
{
    std::cout << "< operator was called" << std::endl;
    if (this != &other)
    {
        if (lname.compare(other.lname) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to use this in a more complicated set of things and it is failing - just want to make sure this much is right.

Comment: The first `return false;` is kind of messing it up. It could also do with being `const`.

Comment: What type is `lname`? Could you not just return `lname.compare(other.lname) < 0` or something like that?

Comment: Since you don't specify what `compare` does it's hard to tell if you're doing it correctly.

Comment: Bagh, sorry, that return false wasnt meant to be there.

Comment: why use `== 0` for an `operator<`? why the self-identity checks? why the `if` statement instead of just returning the result of comparison?

Comment: lname is a string and it is comparison of strings, thusly. I spose rather than the implementation of the method I just wanted to make sure that the argument I passed in was "right", and, mainly, could be used with std::sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your `operator<` doesn't allow the left side to be `const`.  Changing the function signature to

```
bool User::operator<(const User& other) const
```

is an improvement.  But I would actually recommend making it a non-member function instead:

```
class User {
public:
    friend bool operator<(const User& u1, const User& u2);
    // ...
};

bool operator<(const User& u1, const User& u2)
{
    // ...
}
```

For one thing, it's a little more legible in my opinion.

But also, it sometimes makes a technical difference.  With a non-member function, the expression `a < b` attempts implicit conversions on both `a` and `b` to see if your `operator<` is a viable overload.  But with a member function, implicit conversions can apply to `b`, but not to `a`: `a` must be of type `User` or a derived type.  This can lead to surprising situations where `a < b` compiles but `b < a` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It seems better to me to hide the 'lname' field as private.

```
return lname.compare(other.getName()) < 0;
```

Comment: Why do you think his lname is not private?

Comment: This answer makes no sense, `User::operator<` is a member function of `User`, and so is always able to members of `User`s regardless of whether they are private or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bool User::operator<(const User& other) const
{
    return lname.compare(other.lname) < 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to implement `operator<` is as a const-function:

```
bool User::operator<( const User& other ) const
```

This means that the function does not modify its members and thus can be called on const instances of your class.